# streaming audio from m3u8 file onto vlc player

Tags: vlc-media-player, audio-streaming

I have an audio URL with "m3u8" extension. 
I am trying to stream this audio to an MP3 OR MP4 file using VLC Media Player , but vlc doesnt play the stream. What should be my profile settings under: stream output> profile

Thank you in advance.